Is this called a balcony or a corridor?
Say on the first floor of a school building, we have several classes. In front of the classes, there is a passage. So, one side of the passage are class doors and one side is a barrier. If students look down over the barrier, they see the schoolyard.


(Source)
Is the passage called a balcony or a corridor?
If the school building were just a house, I would call it balcony. But there are several classes next to each other in the above picture.

It is a sort of balcony, but I think I would call it a walkway, since its function is getting from place to place rather than sitting out.

There may be a technical architectural term.
Most of the time you don't actually need a name for it.
If you do need to call it by something, you could use "corridor" if you are using the space as a means to walk from one room to another, or "balcony" if you are using the space as a means to look out over the courtyard.
That is you could use either word depending on context.

It is a corridor.
M+W defines corridor: 'a passageway (as in a hotel or office building) into which compartments or rooms open'
Collins Dictionary defines it similarly: 'A corridor is a long passage in a building, with doors and rooms on one or both sides.'
Google has a similar definition:
'a long passage in a building from which doors lead into rooms'

But corridors aren't usually open to the air.

Chambers has ... "A passageway or gallery communicating with separate rooms or dwellings in a building or compartments in a railway train" which fits the picture quite nicely. However I agree that if you told me there was a corridor I wouldn't picture this. balcony isn't quite right for the reason Kate stated elsewhere. I would expect something described as a walkway to be more like a footbridge. gallery ["1. A covered walk. 2. A long balcony"] is technically right but has too many other (more commonly used) meanings to be perfect.

@timchessish …dwellings in a building or compartments in a railway train" I don't consider an outdoor, open or external  corridor to belong INSIDE a building.

@timchessish - I think 'gallery' is perfect and customary.  I would not see any problem at all with a context-rich fragment like 'the gallery that runs along the front of the first floor'.

Note that most of these dictionary definitions use the word "in." While the structure pictured is part of a building, it's not indoors, and I think "corridor" would more usually be assumed to be indoors.

@Michael I do like gallery, but I also think context is necessary. Actually, when would you need a word for that without having the context. Maybe I was overthinking.
